# Chypher query not working with regular expression

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to make a cypher query that returns all the nodes that have a relation with another node and the property X of the relation matches a regular expression. I have tried this:

```
match (n)-[r]-() where r.X =~ '(?i).*String.*' return n limit 100
```

But it's not working for a property that I am sure it exists. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing an exact comparison (instead of a regex) for a property value you know definitely exists in your graph?

Comment: [Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=24mvji) that shows your your query working correctly. (The query was modified slightly to remove duplicate result nodes.) Can you provide a console that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: remember that properties are case sensitive

Comment: am I not ignoring the case with the (?i) at the beginning of the regular expression?

Comment: @cybersam I have tested the query on the console and it works even when is not working for me, don't know why... I really don't know what the problem is!

Comment: I have added a print screen with the problem I am having... The query is not returning anything, not even for equals the entire string.

Comment: Any chance to share your database with me? michael at neo4j.org Thanks.